# Como buscar en un array que esta dentro de un json

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tengo algo mas o menos así y lo que trato es que busque y me muestre el json que contenga en el array de asignaturas por ejemplo 7-4 tengo este array y intento con algo "Lo dejo abajo del Json" pero no funciona

```
{
    "asignaturas" : [ 
        "Religion 5-4"
    ],
    "nombre" : "juan",
    "apellido" : "andres",
},{
    "asignaturas" : [ 
        "Religion 5-4"
    ],
    "nombre" : "juan",
    "apellido" : "andres",
},{
    "asignaturas" : [ 
        "Religion 7-4"
    ],
    "nombre" : "juan",
    "apellido" : "andres",
}
```

y necesito filtrar todas las que en asignaturas tengan por ejemplo 7-2 sin importar lo que esta antes osea que por ejemplo me muestre todo el JSON del que en asignaturas cuente con "lo que sea 7-4" intente con

```
const grupo = doc.filter(grupos => grupos.asignaturas.indexOf('Religion 7-4'))
```

pero tengo que especificar todo y la idea es que si pongo 5-4 busque aunque no este religion escrito pero si coloco solo 7-4 no funciona ayuda por fa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta con:

`doc.filter(d=>d.asignaturas.find(a=>a.includes('7-4')))`

Con filter ponemos una condición para retornar los datos. Para que se cumpla la condición tienes que tener dentro del array asignatura un valor que contenga '7-4'.

Para buscar dentro de un texto usas includes y te retorna true o false si existe el texto o no.

Find te devuelve el primer registro que cumpla la condición y para filter cualquier valor diferente de null o false es true.

Comment: Esta de aqui me parece buena solucion.

Comment: De verdad gracias, me funciono perfectamente gracias por apoyar

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = [
    {
        "asignaturas" : [ 
            "Religion 5-4"
        ],
        "nombre" : "juan",
        "apellido" : "andres",
    },
    {
        "asignaturas" : [ 
            "Religion 5-4"
        ],
        "nombre" : "juan",
        "apellido" : "andres",
    }
    ,
    {
        "asignaturas" : [ 
            "Religion 7-4"
        ],
        "nombre" : "juan",
        "apellido" : "andres",
    }
];

const grupo = obj.filter(group => 
     group.asignaturas.filter( item => item.includes("7-4")).length 
)
console.log(grupo);
      /*
         output:
     {
        "asignaturas" : [ 
            "Religion 7-4"
        ],
        "nombre" : "juan",
        "apellido" : "andres",
     }
       */
```

Comment: con el .length no devolvera solo un numero?

Comment: Filter devuelve un array vacío si no encuentra lo que busca, y un array vacío es "", lo cual se traduce a true si conoce cómo funciona la conversión de array a booleanos. Pero "" es 0 en tamaño, lo cual es falso, y solo sería positivo en contra lugar, lo cual sería cierto. 1 o cualquier otro número es true.